# The $p$-divisible groups which arise from an abelian variety over characteristic $p$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Can you classify all conditions for $p$-divisible groups arising from an abelian variety? For example, $2\dim = \mbox{height}$.

Comment: I believe it's known, attributed to Serre and to Oort, that for an algebraically closed field k of characteristic p, the map from abelian varieties to quasi-isogeny classes of p-divisible groups which are self-dual (also understood up to quasi-isogeny) is essentially surjective. Beyond that, I don't know what's known; it'd be nice to hear something more nuanced.